# how does the inline function work in C++?

Tags: c++, inline

now I have 2 c++ source files: test9.cpp test10.cpp, they both have a inline function with the same name.

test9.cpp:

```
1 #include <iostream>
2 using namespace std;
3 void test();
4 inline void f1()
5 {
6     cout << "inline f1 in test9.cpp" << endl;
7 }   
8 int main()
9 {
10     f1();
11     test();
12     return 0;
13 }
```

test10.cpp:

```
1 #include <iostream>
2 using namespace std;
3 inline void f1()
4 {
5     cout << "inline f1 in test10.cpp" << endl;
6 }   
7 void test()
8 {
9     f1();
10 }
```

now compile them with g++:   g++ test9.cpp test10.cpp    ./a.out   I get the following result:

```
inline f1 in test9.cpp
inline f1 in test9.cpp
```

what's wrong? I thought it would be: "inline f1 in test9.cpp inline f1 in test10.cpp"
who can tell me why? how does the g++ compiler treats the inline function?

Comment: Undefined behaviour; the compiler can do anything it wants.

Comment: Note that nowadays the compiler optimization called *inlining* has nothing to do with the linkage specifier `inline`. Theorically the second is a hint to the compiler to do the first, but nowadays compilers are smarter than humans (For optimization purposes, there is no Skynet yet :) ), so modern compilers ignore that hints and check every function for inlining, not only which you hinted with `inline`.

Comment: So the answer is: Undefined. The compiler is free to decide which functions will be inlined, so don't use the `inline` keyword. Let the compiler do the job.

Comment: The main thing the inline keyword does is say that "this method is local to this compilation unit and should not cause binder-time name conflicts with the same-named method elsewhere".  The assumption is that a given-named inlined method is identical everywhere in the app.

Comment: @AlanStokes I don't think *compiler* is free to do "anything it wants". Compiler is only free to either inline the code it knows about, or do a call and let linker decide what function gets called. Compiler does not have enough knowledge to know if UB is going to be invoked or not.

Comment: @Manu343726 In order for the compiler to inline a function, the compiler must see the definition of the function. When the function is referenced from multiple translation units, that is very hard without `inline`, which allows the definition to be visible in all those translation units. I'd say they're still related.

Comment: @hyde Don't think you can outsmart the compiler. Even if you can today, the same is not necessarily true tomorrow. :) (I do seem to recall one link-time diagnostic if function definitions do not match, but I do not recall which compiler/linker that was.)

Comment: @hyde: It's not about the compiler developing sentience, detecting the UB and "deciding" to do something crazy for the sake of it. UB is actually, more often than not, undetectable in the general case. No, this is about an invariant being broken, such that assumptions made internally no longer hold, and *unexpected*/incongruous behaviour results.

Comment: @HotLicks: But it still has external linkage unless you specifically state otherwise. The keyword permits multiple definitions but that doesn't mean the function is "local" to anything.

Comment: One important point is that the keyword is only a "suggestion" that the method be inlined -- if it cannot be inlined for some reason then the compiler is allowed to generate it as an out-of-line method and call it in the conventional fashion.

Comment: @HotLicks: Yes, physical inlining is essentially orthogonal to the use of the `inline` keyword, but the other standard-mandated requirements _always_ apply.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Yes, it has external linkage, but multiple instances of the method must not conflict.

Comment: @HotLicks: Of course not. That's true of _all_ functions. :) See my answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While the compiler will allow you (nay, *require* you!) to redefine functions marked `inline`, the default of external linkage still applies, so you are breaking the One Definition Rule. This results in undefined behaviour and the outcome that you are seeing.

> `[C++11: 7.1.2/4]:` An inline function shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is odr-used and shall have exactly the same definition in every case (3.2). *[..]*